# shell errors running php exec

Tags: php, shell, sh

I have a PHP script that executes a shell command to find the common items between two files given.  This is the beginning of my PHP script:

```
$E7Bonded_File = "/opt/IBM/custom/NAC_Dslam/junk/PortParameter_E7_Bonded_cust_stats.csv";
$E7Single_File = "/opt/IBM/custom/NAC_Dslam/junk/PortParameter_E7_Single_cust_stats.csv";
$E7Common_File = "/opt/IBM/custom/NAC_Dslam/junk/Common_tn_SingleBonded_E7_cust_stats.csv";
//only do this once, with old single/bonded filenames. This will be a list to add to the existing Common file.
exec ("comm -12 <(cut -d ',' -f2 $E7Single_File| sort) <(cut -d ',' -f2 $E7Bonded_File| sort)", $outputCommon);
```

I see this error message when I run the script:

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `comm -12 <(cut -d ',' -f2 /opt/IBM/custom/NAC_Dslam/junk/PortParameter_E7_Single_cust_stats.csv| sort) <(cut -d ',' -f2 /opt/IBM/custom/NAC_Dslam/junk/PortParameter_E7_Bonded_cust_stats.csv| sort)'
```

I checked, and the parentheses look ok for my `exec()` line.

When I run the shell command at the command line it returns a listing of numbers like I expect:

```
 comm -12 <(cut -d ',' -f2 junk/PortParameter_E7_Single_cust_stats.csv| sort) <(cut -d ',' -f2 junk/PortParameter_E7_Bonded_cust_stats.csv| sort)
```

I looked online and I seem to be using `exec()` correctly.  I want the numbers returned to be stored as an array, `$outputCommon`.

Any ideas about this error message?

*********Update on answer***************

My solution wound up being a combination of both mario and miken32/my co-worker

1. Adding `#!/bin/bash` at the top of my php script, and
2. Adding `/bin/bash -c`  as follows:

   exec("/bin/bash -c /opt/IBM/custom/NAC_Dslam/Common_list.sh", $outputShell);
3. After I moved the comm part to a shell script:

Common_list.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
 comm -12 <(cut -d ',' -f2 /opt/IBM/custom/NAC_Dslam/junk/PortParameter_E7_Single_cust_stats.csv| sort) <(cut -d ',' -f2 /opt/IBM/custom/NAC_Dslam/junk/PortParameter_E7_Bonded_cust_stats.csv| sort)
```

Comment: Which shell are you using for testing, and which one is linked as `/bin/sh`? dash does not support expression pipes AFAIK.

Comment: I did "which sh" at the command line and it returned /bin/sh.  I added this line to my script, exec("which sh",$throwaway);
var_dump($throwaway); and it returned /bin/sh as well.  I've used pipes in commands I execute in php exec before.

Comment: Is the issue specific to `comm`? Or to Linux? Also check the description of the "shell" tag. That said, your question is off-topic because it really lacks a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error typically comes up for non-bash shells, which don't support `<()` expression pipes.

- On Ubuntu/Debian servers the default `/bin/sh` is typically `dash`.
- Check for symlinked binaries:

  ```
  me@snip:~$ ls -l /bin/sh
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jul 16  2017 /bin/sh -> dash
  ```
- Or as @theotherguy mentioned, bash runs as restricted_shell when started as `sh`.
- See $_ENV[SHELL] on what Apache/PHP use as default. Change environment vars.
- Either adapt that, or wrap the [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/shell_exec) cmdline with `/bin/bash -c '…'`.

Comment: Did you mean to type "dash" above there?

Comment: mario-It's not clear what I need to do with what you're saying in your answer.

Comment: Even when `sh` is bash, it'll run in a compatibility more where process substitution is not available

Comment: @thatotherguy So it'll only work for real login or interactive shells? // Then `-l` or `+o restricted` might be necessary.

Comment: No, it's fine in non-interactive shells. It just requires that `bash` is invoked as `bash`, such as with `bash -c`

Comment: Could you show me how I would apply what you're saying with an example with my stuff please? I'm not sure what you're saying.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest solution would be to make this into an executable script on the server:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ ! -r "$1" ]] || [[ ! -r "$2" ]]; then
    printf "File not found\n" >&2
    exit 1
fi

comm -12 <(cut -d ',' -f2 "$1"| sort) <(cut -d ',' -f2 "$2"| sort)
```

And then call that from PHP:

```
$E7Bonded_File = escapeshellarg("/opt/IBM/custom/NAC_Dslam/junk/PortParameter_E7_Bonded_cust_stats.csv");
$E7Single_File = escapeshellarg("/opt/IBM/custom/NAC_Dslam/junk/PortParameter_E7_Single_cust_stats.csv");

//only do this once, with old single/bonded filenames. This will be a list to add to the existing Common file.
exec ("/usr/local/bin/your_script.sh $E7Single_File $E7Bonded_File", $outputCommon);
```

**Always** escape your shell arguments with [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) even if you think they're safe.

Comment: I tried this, and running the shell script with the command has the same complaint.  That's strange, since the command runs at the command line.

Comment: I find that hard to believe since the shebang tells it to run under bash. Did you mark the script executable?

Comment: Yes, I made it chmod 777.  I got something to work.  I moved the comm part to the shell script like you  have, with bin bash at the top, and I run the shell script like this from my php script: exec("/bin/bash -c /opt/IBM/custom/NAC_Dslam/Common_list.sh", $outputShell); I also have the #!/bin/bash at the top of my php script.

Comment: BTW, the shell script ran from the command line, just not from the php script until I made those changes.

Comment: It was adding /bin/bash/ -c in front of my exec in the php script that seemed to help

Answer (score 0):

when checking the script with a [linter](https://www.shellcheck.net), it complains that:

```
comm -12 <(cut -d ',' -f2 junk/PortParameter_E7_Single_cust_stats.csv| sort) <(cut -d ',' -f2 junk/PortParameter_E7_Bonded_cust_stats.csv| sort)
     ^-- SC2039: In POSIX sh, process substitution is undefined.
```

this happens when I define shebang `#!/bin/sh`, while `#!/bin/bash` does not complain... therefore the answer might be, to run the script with `/usr/bin/bash`. `escapeshellarg()` is indeed useful.

...

try `shell_exec()`, simply because `exec()` should not invoke any shell. the one returns the output as string and the other can return an array.
alternatively, you can explicitly invoke bash with `exec()`:

```
exec('/bin/bash -c "  command  "', $stdOut);
```

Comment: Are you saying to run the comm command as a shell script using #!/usr/bin/bash. I'm trying that right now, and it has the same error, when executed from my php script.

Answer (score 0):

So in case anyone else still needs to get substitution working in command execution in PHP, there is super dumb simple thing to do:

```
$a = 'Hello substitution';
var_dump(shell_exec("bash -c 'cat <(echo $a)'"));
```

Results in:

```
string(19) "Hello substitution
"
```

Which is expected/desired.